# Bypass facebook login on browser if already logged in on facebook app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

Is there a way to have the site (having sign in with facebook functionailty) grab the info from the Facebook app rather than grabbing from the Facebook site in the browser?

The current issue is that no one is actually logged into Facebook on their mobile browser because they use Facebook on their phone via an app.  This requires them to log into Facebook on their mobile browser, which is actually an additional step. So if user is already logged into facebook using facebook app then on browser user should not ask to give login details again when user clicked on `sign in with facebook` link.

I am using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem and `OmniAuth` support to achieve sign in with facebook functionality.

Comment: No, that is not possible. There is no connection between the Facebook app and the browser that would let the latter know that the user is logged in to Facebook in the former.